# plots in overlapping multiple axes MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, axes

I have 2 axes in my GUI which overlap (they have same positions). 2 separate radio buttons trigger each. When one is triggered, the other should be suppressed. I'll show different plots in each. However, when I use 'Visible', only axes are gone not the plots. How can I solve this?

```
value(1) = get(S.rbh_1,'value'); value(2) = get(S.rbh_2,'value');

if value(1) == 1
    set(S.rbh_2,'value',0);
    set(S.axes1,'Visible','on');
    set(S.axes2,'Visible','off');
elseif value(2) == 1
    set(S.rbh_1,'value',0);
    set(S.axes1,'Visible','off');
    %cla(S.axes1);
    set(S.axes2,'Visible','on');
end
```

If I use cla(), I cannot draw previously existing plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is aminimal exemple reproducing your problem:

```
ezplot('x^2');
set(gca, 'Visible', 'off');
```

Actually, this is a normal behavior. According to the documentation:

> The Visible property of an axes object does not affect the children of
>   axes.

To make both the axes and all its children elements invisible, you can use `findall` in combination with `arrayfun`. Just replace:

```
set(gca,'Visible','off');
```

with

```
arrayfun(@(x) set(x, 'Visible', 'off'), findall(gca));
```

In your exemple, you have to replace `gca` by `S.axes1` or `S.axes2`.

Best,